# In docker contaier warfile folder is not created in webapps after start the tomcat

Tags: docker, dockerfile, war

When we run the tomcat then in webapps, folder of war file is get created like if we have name.war file then name folder is get created in webapps after running the tomcat

but when we deploy war file by docker using dockerfile then in docker container we have tomcat folder and in webapps we have war file  and after running the dockerfile tomcat get start application is also running but in webapp's folder folder of war file is not created.
like I have  name.war in webapps in docker container but after running tomcat no name folder was present in webapps.

so if we need to do  some small changes in jsp in war file then we need to do whole deployment of war file like stop container build dockerfile run dockerfile  etc. so if we have that folder of warfile in webapps then we can change jsp or js easily.
 so how can we  get the warfile folder after running the tomcat in docker container.

To build the Dockerfile:

```
docker build -t tomcat .
```

tomcat is name of image

To run the Dockerfile:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 tomcat
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:7-jre

MAINTAINER shri

ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat

ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH

COPY tomcat $CATALINA_HOME

ADD  newui.war  $CATALINA_HOME/webapps

CMD $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh && tail -F $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out

EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: Any unusual tomcat configuration?

Comment: no ... even logs also not get displayed in tomcat 's logs folder in docker container so i get the logs in docker container on my host logs folder by this command                                                                                           
      docker run \-d \-p 8085:8085 \-v /usr/local/tomcat/logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs \tomcat
    or 
      docker run \-d \-v /usr/local/tomcat/logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs \tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the war from the host to the container, by mounting the folder containing the war on the host.

```
docker run -v /.../tomcat:/usr/local/tomcat -p 8080:8080 --name tomcat tomcat
```

Where `/.../tomcat` is path to a yet non existing tomcat folder. Now whenever you have a new war file, copy it to `/.../tomcat` directory and just restart the container.

```
docker restart tomcat
```

Note that there is no need to rebuild the container.

Comment: ok thanks .. but my question is how i  get the war file folder which was not display in tomcats webapps folder in docker container after running the tomcat , so  how i will  get that war file folder in webapps